# If a number is divisible by two others, then it's divisible by their lcm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, least-common-multiple

> Prove that if $c$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$, then $c$ is a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$

Nobody in my class has found a way to do it. Whatever I try, I always come to the conclusion that I need the exact same thing I'm trying to prove...to finish my proof.

Our instructor gave a hint though, saying 'if $c$ is a counterexample, then $c-\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ is a counterexample'. Unfortunately, I don't understand the hint. I tried to execute induction and proof by contradiction, but nothing leads anywhere.

Comment: This is the definition of the lcm ... there is nothing to prove. If you have another definition (perhaps the wrong one using $\leq$?), please add it.

Comment: That's why we were all so puzzled. What I typed is the exact question...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I've always thought that the definition is the one with $\leq$. It's not clear if the $lcm$ exists if defined the other way.

Comment: Often lcm($a,b$) is defined as $ab/$gcd($a,b$) and then it could make sense. But then the proof is still trivial.

Comment: In our book it is indeed said that ab = ggd(a,b)*lcm(a,b). That statement has been proven by our teacher, but for the rest of the lecture he just used what I'm trying to proof without any commentary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove is that every common multiple of $a,b$ is a multiple of the lcm.

Suppose $d=lcm(a,b)$ and $d \nmid  c$ then we have $c=dx+y$ with $0\lt y \lt d$

So $y=c-dx$ and $a,b|(c-dx)$ which is a contradiction with the assumption that $d$ is the lcm.

Comment: Thanks! The hint also makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, but equivalent, constructive proof: Let $A\triangleq\{m_1, m_2, \cdots\}$ be the set of all common multiples of $a$ and $b$, with $m_1<m_2<\cdots$.  We'll show that $m_k=k\cdot m_1$, where $m_1$ is obviously the lcm, and $k\ge 1.$

Proof: Consider $m_2$ first.  Since $m_1$ and $m_2$ are both common multiples of $a$ and $b$, clearly so is $m_2-m_1$, i.e. $m_2-m_1\in A$.  It follows that $m_2-m_1=m_1$, as $m_2$ is the smallest element in $A$ that's greater than $m_1$.  Hence $m_2=2m_1$.  By the same token, $m_3-m_2=m_4-m_3=\cdots=m_1$, implying $m_k=k\cdot m_1$.